# Insert cropped images to PowerPoint slides for selected images in a folder. Up to a max of 6 images per slide?

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint, crop, placeholder

I have hundreds of photographs for a single sample that need to be cropped then inserted into PowerPoint slides.  Six photographs per slide in portrait mode with the same text label for all photographs. The PowerPoint photo album only lets me import a maximum of 4 photographs.
I found some code that I have meshed with a custom placeholder layout that counts the number of images I select for that particular sample then places one photograph per new slide.  However, I need 6 photographs per slide. The code below does not include the cropping code.

Can anyone help?

Code posted below

```
Public Function GetLayout( _
LayoutName As String, _
Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout

If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
    Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
End If

Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
        Set GetLayout = oLayout
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function

Sub ImportABunch2()
Dim i As Long
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oPicture As Shape, oContentHolder As Shape


Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog

Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogOpen)
With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
End With

If dlgOpen.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

For i = 1 To dlgOpen.SelectedItems.Count

''Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide
Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.slides
Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(oSlides.Count + 1, GetLayout("Smiley"))
    For Each oContentHolder In oSlide.Shapes
        If oContentHolder.Type = msoPlaceholder And oContentHolder.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoAutoShape Then
            Set oPicture = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=dlgOpen.SelectedItems(i), _
                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100)
              
            GoTo NextSlide
        End If
    Next

NextSlide:
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
Sub ImportABunch3()

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oPic As Shape

Dim lCurrentRound As Long
lCurrentRound = 1

' Edit these to suit:
'strPath = "C:\Users\"

strFileSpec = "*.jpg"

strTemp = Dir(strPath & strFileSpec)

Do While strTemp <> ""

If lCurrentRound = 1 Then   ' add a new slide
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.slides.Add(ActivePresentation.slides.Count + 
1, ppLayoutCustom)
End If
        Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=0, _
        Top:=0, _
        Width:=-1, _
        Height:=-1)

    ' Edit the Left/Top values below if you want to place
    ' the images in specific locations
         Select Case lCurrentRound
        Case 1
            oPic.Left = 25
            oPic.Top = 30

        Case 2
            oPic.Left = 260
            oPic.Top = 30

        Case 3
            oPic.Left = 25
            oPic.Top = 250

        Case 4
            oPic.Left = 260
            oPic.Top = 250

        Case 5
            oPic.Left = 25
            oPic.Top = 470
        
        Case 6
            oPic.Left = 260
            oPic.Top = 470

        End Select

If lCurrentRound = 6 Then
    lCurrentRound = 1
Else
    lCurrentRound = lCurrentRound + 1
End If

strTemp = Dir

''Call Align_all_images

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you found something that worked. Just a note: it's considered courteous to credit the source of code that you've copied from elsewhere rather than written yourself, and even better, to mention any changes you've made to the code to make it work the way you want it to, when the original doesn't suffice.  Here's the original:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00352_Batch_Insert_a_folder_full_of_pictures-_one_per_slide.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Steve. I am new to this and will try and be more careful in my posts next time.  I am not a code writer so I found and adapted the code you referenced. I added two more cases for my needs and changed  - If lCurrentRound = 1 Then to  If lCurrentRound =  6 Then.  Thanks